# Unable to create bundle.appxupload file for windows Packaging project for desktop bridge application, UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-application, appxmanifest, packager

Currently I am able to build my application in release mode having Windows Packaging project as a Startup project and my UWP as Entry point to it where desktop application running in background. 
Previously I had created a Upload file to be uploaded on store successfully for UWP app. For its next release I implemented Desktop application using Packager project. So I have added all the necessary parameters to be used when I launch the app. Also I am able to associate the packager project to the store successfully. But when I try to generate a bundle file for Packager it takes long time and does not provide any result(no Upload bundle file) also there are no errors listed in the Error windows. 
it just creates a dependencies and Packager_2.1.250.0_x86.appxsym. No other files are created.
What changes do I need to make when I create bundle file to be uploaded on the store for a Packager project?

Comment: Could you try to build package in different environment with same process?  To exclude  original environment  issue.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot change the configuration of the Desktop application to x64 as it is 32-bit version code, and so VS is not allowing me to change UWP and Packager to be changed to x64. (throws an error : Mismatch between Processor Architecture).

Comment: It's hard to reproduce with the little information, I think you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)and check if you have missed something.